# Find the right $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would like to show that $f(n) = 4n - \log_2(n) - 3$ is greater than $\alpha n$ for a certain $\alpha>0$. How could I find such a $\alpha$? I am not that sure such $\alpha$ exists. I want to show that $f(n) \in \Theta(n)$. It is trivial that $4n - \log_2(n) - 3 \leq 4n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but not for the other inequality.

Comment: Use $\log_2(n)\le n-1$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Every $\alpha\in (0,1)$ will do.

Comment: @amsmath Could you develop how you got $\alpha\in (0,1)?$ I got that $f(n) \geq 3n-2$, but not sure for the rest.

Comment: Since $f(1) = 1$, you must have $\alpha < 1$. So, let's prove that $3n-2>\alpha n$ for any $n\ge 1$ and any $\alpha<1$. The inequality is equivalent to $(3-\alpha)n > 2$. This is true for $n=1$ and hence for any $n\ge 1$.

Answer (score -1):

Fix $\alpha>0$. Now observe that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\log_2n}{n}=0
\ .$$
According to the definition of the limit, there is a natural number $N$ such that $({\log_2n})/{n}$ is smaller than $\alpha$ for every $n\geq N$.
Therefore for large enough $n$s, we get
$$
\log_2 n<\alpha n\ . 
$$
Finally using above results we get the following inequality for large enough $n$s
$$
4n-\log_2n-3\geq4n-\alpha n-3\geq(4-2\alpha)n
$$
Now let $\alpha$ take arbitrarily small values...